# double PCR with tailed primer

Tags: pcr, primer

I would like to make a double PCR with universal tailed primer. The first PCR would make a tailed amplicon. The second PCR would generate fragment labeled with fluorescent dye. Here is my protcole. Could you tell me if I am wrong ?

- is my second PCR forward primer well designed to fit with the tail ?
- What would be the ratio of primer to use if I want to merge the two PCR into one ?

## Fist PCR ( works )

In bold, you have the tail M13(-20)

Forward : 5'-**GTAAAACGACGGCCAGT**TCTGCAGTTGTACTGAGTGAA-3'
Reverse : 5'-AAAGCGTGCAGCTGATATTT-3'

#### Mix for 1 sample

- Water              = 15.8µL
- MgCl2 (25mM)       = 18µL
- Buffer (5x)        = 6µL
- dNTP (4mM)         = 1.5µL
- Forward(20pmol/µL) = 1µL
- Reverse(20pmol/µL) = 1µL
- GoTaq (5U/µL)      = 0.15 µL
- DNA (50ng/µL)      = 1 µL

## Second PCR ( not working = no fragment signal )

Forward : 5'-[FAM]-**GTAAAACGACGGCCAGT**-3'
Reverse : 5'-AAAGCGTGCAGCTGATATTT-3'

#### Mix for 1 sample

- Water              = 15.8µL
- MgCl2 (25mM)       = 18µL
- Buffer (5x)        = 6µL
- dNTP (4mM)         = 1.5µL
- Forward(20pmol/µL) = 1µL
- Reverse(20pmol/µL) = 1µL
- GoTaq (5U/µL)      = 0.15 µL
- DNA (50ng/µL)      = **1µL from my previous amplicon**

Comment: Are you forced to use the reverse like this? I've been taught to avoid A/T ends and stretches of more than 3 consecutive C/Gs or A/Ts; your reverse has both. Besides that, did you try a gradient for the anneaing temperature?

Comment: No, I can change the primer ! Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your query. I can say that in my lab we are also using fluorescent dye (for SSR detection). But we are doing it with a one step approach:

Our forward primers are like yours preceded by the fluo sequence (M13-forward primer). But instead of making a second PCR, we add directly the fluo primer (let's called it M13-FAM) in the first PCR. It is REALLY important to put your M13-forward primer in lower quantity than the reverse one (factor 10 for me). To achieve that I use 0.1mM primer solutions and I mix my primers before

**For 96 wells (20µL/well)**

### Primer Mix

- 1.25 µL of M13-F primer
- 12.5 µL of R primer
- 240 µL of water

### PCR Mix

- 200 µL of Primer Mix
- 20 µL of M13-FAM
- Master Mix 1mL
- Water 1mL

Comment: Thanks ! You answer to my question perfectly ! I was doing 2 PCRs to check my primers first . But my final goal is what you did .
Could you give me your primers ? To check if I am not wrong ? I m not sure if M13-tail primer and M13-FAM have to be in same orientation 5'-3'